# PHP $wpdb-query - Cannot parse variable?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add more values ​​into my database but don't know how to do it. Right now, I'm trying with 
`$wpdb->query`.

`$wpdb->query` will work fine if I do not put `$this->tables->address ()` into.

What should I do to put a variable inside my query? or do u have some better ideas?

MY CODE:

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO '.$this->tables->address().' (address, zipcode_Id) VALUES ('street 23', '7100'), ('street 24', '8700'), ('street 25', '9900')");
```

Comment: Welcome. You should probably [check the manual on strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Try this `$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO '".$this->tables->address()."' (address, zipcode_Id) VALUES ('street 23', '7100'), ('street 24', '8700'), ('street 25', '9900')");`

Comment: _“What should I do to put a variable inside my query?”_ - learn the basics … https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how it should like. You open double quotes, but closing before variable with single quote. This should look like:

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ".$this->tables->address()." (address, zipcode_Id) VALUES ('street 23', '7100'), ('street 24', '8700'), ('street 25', '9900')");
```

Comment: Lucek: ohhh... it worked. Thank you very much! :) u saved my day..